# Find the standard matrix of $T$ with respect to$S=\left \{ 1,x \right \}$ and $S'=\left \{ 1,x,x^{2} \right \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$B =\left \{1+x,3+2x  \right \}B'=\left \{ 2,3-x,5+x^{2} \right \}$

you are given the matrix of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{P}^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2}$ with respect to $B$ and $B'$ is:
$\left [ T \right ]_{B,B'}=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -3\\ 
-2 &4 \\ 
 7& 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Compute $T(6-11x)$

Find the "Standard matrix" of $T$ with respect to $S=\left \{ 1,x \right \}$ and $S'=\left \{ 1,x,x^{2} \right \}$

Recompute $T(6-11x)$ using your standard matrix.

So I was able to find $6-11x=C_{1}(1+x)+C_{2}(3+2x)$ where $=C_{1}=-45$ and $=C_{2}=17$ which i used for $\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -3\\ 
-2 &4 \\ 
 7& 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-45\\ 
17
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-276\\ 
158\\ 
-298
\end{bmatrix}$

which gave me my answer for the first part $T(6-11x)=-\frac{1}{2}\left ( 784+79x+149x^{2} \right )$

I am lost trying to find the standard matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you managed to compute $T(6-11x)$, you surely also can compute $T(1)$ and $T(x)$. Why does that already solve the problem?

If you do not see that immediately then make sure that you understand that
$\left [ T \right ]_{B,B'}=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -3\\ 
-2 &4 \\ 
 7& 1
\end{bmatrix}$ just means that
$$T(1+x)=5\cdot 2-2(3-x)+7(5+x^2),\quad T(3+2x)=-3\cdot 2+4(3-x)+1\cdot(5+x^2),$$
and that I did not have to calculate anything for that but just had to look at the columns of the matrix to read off the coefficients. If you are working with the standard bases $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S'$, then things should be even easier.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to find the standard matrix for this problem without a $T(p(x))=...$ I know that the answer will be the same, but I don't know how to find $\left \lfloor T \right \rfloor_{S,S'}$

Comment: If you have calculated $T(1)$ and $T(x)$ then you can also write down $T(a+bx)$, if that helps you. You will see afterwards that it was not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that edit made it much easier for me to visualize

Comment: You are welcome.